# How to initiate the directory owner to non-root user in dockerized gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

First of all I am not asking how to run as non-root user.
I ran the gitlab runner as follows.

docker-compose.yml

```
gitlab-runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:v16.2.2'
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    environment:
        TZ: "Asia/Seoul"
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - '/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    environment:
```

config.toml

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    privileged = true
    ...
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/home/sunny/work:/builds", "/cache"]
    pull_policy = ["if-not-present"]
    ...
```

If the runner is triggered, Git project source is cloning "/home/sunny/work/XXXXXXXX/...".
The owner of the directory is always '**root**'.

```
sunny@sunny-mini:~/work$ ll
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 3 sunny sunny 4.0K 11월 17 15:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 sunny sunny 4.0K 11월 10 13:52 ../
drwxrwxrwx 3 root  root  4.0K 11월 17 15:56 wAXF7Y9q/
```

How can I change the owner to **non-root user**?

I also tried changing to execute as non-root user. But the owner of the directory is initiated always "root".